# programmatically created table does not work

Tags: objective-c

I created a UITableView programmatically, but none of its methods were called. I must have missed something:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...     
    self.transactionView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, CARD_VIEW_Y, 320.0, CARD_VIEW_H)];
    self.transactionView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.transactionView];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wire both the `delegate` AND the `dataSource` of the tableview. `UITableViewDataSource` provides the methods to fill the actual table with data.